# How to provide an expiration time for a subscription in Google Cloud PubSub

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to set an expiration time for a subscription.

This is how options looks like as suggested by the official docs:

https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/0.28.x/global#CreateSubscriptionRequest
https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/pubsub/0.28.x/global#ExpirationPolicy

```
let options = {
  expirationPolicy: {
    ttl: '86400s',
  },
};
```

Then I got `.google.pubsub.v1.ExpirationPolicy.ttl: object expected` error.

So I tried having an object inside property `ttl` then I got the following error: `The value for 0 is too small. You passed expiration duration in the request, but the minimum value is 24h.`

I'm unable to find the correct format to this.

I'm on @google-cloud/pubsub@0.28.1 and tried upgrading to @google-cloud/pubsub@0.29.1. No luck.

Anyone has experienced this before or know the correct format for `expirationPolicy`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `expirationPolicy` `ttl` needs to be specified as an object with the seconds field as an integer:

```
let options = {
  expirationPolicy: {
    ttl: {
      seconds: 86400
    }
  }
};
```

This is inconsistent with the documentation, so I have [created a GitHub issue](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-pubsub/issues/653) to track the inconsistency.